# Can't use 2D indexing with an unorganized point cloud

Tags: ros, pcl, pcl-conversions, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using perception_pcl package to convert sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2 to pcl::PointXYZRGB and get the rgb or x,y,z data according to the raw and column value according to below code:

pcl::PCLPointCloud2* cloud = new pcl::PCLPointCloud2;
pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZRGB cloud_xyzrgb;

```
// Convert to PCL data type
pcl_conversions::toPCL(*cloud_msg, *cloud);

pcl::fromROSMsg (*cloud_msg, cloud_xyzrgb);

std::cout<<cloud_xyzrgb.height<<"\t"<<cloud_xyzrgb.width<<std::endl;
std::cout<<cloud_xyzrgb.at(1,1)<<std::endl;
```

But when i run this node. i'm getting the below error:

```
1   202403
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pcl::UnorganizedPointCloudException'
  what():  : Can't use 2D indexing with an unorganized point cloud
```

Environment:

```
Depth sensor: intel realsense d455 depth sensor
depth sensor driver: realsense-ros, foxy branch
ros version: ros2 foxy fitzroy
os: ubuntu 20.04 desktop
```

This same approach used to work in ros1 as i can remember. But as i migrated to ros2 foxy, looks like this feature hasn't implemented still now.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/379231/can%27t-use-2d-indexing-with-an-unorganized-point-cloud/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2021-05-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok after few hours of debugging and research i found that their is a parameter in realsense node which enables the pointcloud being publishing to be organized, default being un-organized.
So setting `ordered_pc:=true` made this issue solved.
Here is my full command:

```
ros2 launch realsense2_camera rs_launch.py enable_pointcloud:=true ordered_pc:=true
```

---

Originally posted by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) with karma: 932 on 2021-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1